# GUI using VBA in access. Recordset from query

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, recordset

Making GUI in Access with VBA (first time i saw it in this semester and it looks unusual for me). I got table `Authors` where i got columns `author_id`, `last_name`, `first_name` and table `Books` with columns `author_id`, `book_name`. 
I got button on Form which on click should ask user to input author last name and then search and show all books of this author.

So I trying to find author id from Authors table and then from Books table show all books where author.author_id is equal to books.author_id.

I was thinking that i need to create temp query which contained author_id value and after that create record set with this query using SQLquery like `"SELECT [Books].[book_name] AS [Bookname] FROM [Books] WHERE [Books].[author_id] =  [test].[ID]"` But i stucked here - I trying to just check if this thing working but it says there is an error `3061`

```
Private Sub authorlist_Click()

    Dim dbs As Database, authorsRS, booksRS As Recordset, queryStr, idbynameQuery, srchASurStr, strOutput, srId As String, qdf As QueryDef

    Set dbs = CurrentDb()

    srchASurStr = InputBox("Input author surname, please", , , 100, 100)

    strQuery = "SELECT [Authors].[author_id] AS [ID] FROM [Authors] WHERE [Authors].[last_name] =  " & srchASurStr & ""



    Set authorsRS = dbs.OpenRecordset(strQuery, dbOpenSnapshot)

    With dbs
        Set qdf = .CreateQueryDef("test", strQuery)
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "test"
        .QueryDefs.Delete "test"
    End With


End Sub
```

So could you help me please to understan what's wrong? And is there maybe more simple way to show all books of some author (maybe without using SQL querys)?

Comment: Have you got a form? BTW those field names will drive you insane - most people recommend avoiding anything but alpha and (if you really must) numeric in column and table names, eg, LastName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String values in an SQL statement need to be surrounded with single-quotes (`'`) or double-quotes (`"`):

```
SELECT author_id FROM authors WHERE last_name = "Smith"
```

If written without the quotes:

```
SELECT author_id FROM authors WHERE last_name = Smith
```

`Smith` will be understood to be a field name and not a string value. So your code should look something like this:

```
'Chr returns a string from a character code. 34 is the code for "
strQuery = "SELECT author_id FROM authors WHERE last_name = " & Chr(34) & srchASurStr & Chr(34)
```

In VBA, you can escape double-quotes with a string by doubling them:

```
strQuery = "SELECT author_id FROM authors WHERE last_name = """ & srchASurStr & """"
```

---

**SQL injection**: Keep in mind that if the user inputs a string with `"` in it, there will probably be an error, as the resulting SQL statement has invalid syntax:

```
SELECT author_id FROM authors WHERE last_name = "Smi"th"
```

The right way to avoid this problem is to use parameters.

---

Some notes:

- You can reference a form control within a query: `[Forms]![FormName]![ControlName]`. Thus, you can create a saved query that filters based on a form textbox, instead of using an inputbox.
- Consider using a combobox to have the user select from a list, instead of having the user type free text. The combobox can have multiple columns, with the value of the combobox being the first column (`author_id`) and the displayed value being another expression (`last_name` or `last_name & " " & first_name`). If you set the ColumnWidths property to 0 (for the first column), the next column will be displayed
- If you prefer to use a textbox, consider using the `LIKE` operator in your query, to display all authors whose `last_name` contains the user string:

  `SELECT author_id FROM authors WHERE last_name LIKE "%sm%"`

  will return Smith, Smythe, and Asmodeus.

Comment: But it still can't open recordset

Comment: @DanilGholtsman What error is it giving you? What is the value of strQuery at the point of the error? (`View -> Locals Window`)

Comment: well Query is okay i think cuz  `idbynameQuery : "SELECT [Authors].[author_id] AS [ID] FROM [Authors] WHERE [Authors].[last_name] = Dostoevsky" : Variant/String`
it highlighting with yellow color this 
>Set authorsRS = dbs.OpenRecordset(strQuery, dbOpenSnapshot)
and says that run-time error 3061 and that there should be more parameters

Comment: Yes, because as I said, the query should be `SELECT [Authors].[author_id] AS [ID] FROM [Authors] WHERE [Authors].[last_name] = "Dostoevsky"` (with quotes around `Dostoevsky`). Otherwise, Access evaluates `Dostoevsky` as an expression - either a field or a named parameter, and doesn't find any field/parameter named `Dostoevsky`

Comment: @DanilGholtsman Can you tell me what was missing in the body of the answer, that cleared things up for you in the comments?

Comment: well, idk, I think your asnwer is fine it helped me actually

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set up a form and subform. The form can contain author details and the subform can contain books by that author, you can further add a textbox that the user can fill in with part of the author name. You can then apply a filter to the main form to show all the authors with that name.

```
Me.Filter = "Author Like '*" & Me.Search & "*'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

There are a number of variations on this, the user could select names from a combo or listbox. The form could be a continuous form with a filter / search in the header and so on.

Comment: oh i always avoiding of using all this master forms and actually don't know how to use it properly. where can I find some tutorials and examples about it?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-HA010098674.aspx